# c++ programming principles and practice chapter 7 exercise 4 Symbol_table::get_value always showing error undefined

Tags: c++

From Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practice with C++ Chapter 7 Exercise 4:

"The get_value(), set_value(), is_declared(), and define_name() functions all operate on the variable var_table. Define a class called Symbol_table with a member var_table of type vector and member functions get(), set(), is_declared, and declare(). Rewrite the calculator to use a variable of type Symbol_table."

```
class Variable {
public:
    string name;
    double value;
    bool var;   // variable (true) or constant (false)
    Variable(string s, double d, bool b) :name(s), value(d), var(b) { }
private:
};
class Symbol_table {
public:
    double get(string s);
    void set(string s, double d);
    bool is_declared(string var);
    double declare(string s, double val, bool var = true); //default is variable
private:
    vector<Variable> var_table;
};
double Symbol_table::get_value(string s) {
    // return the value of the Variable names s
    for (Variable& v : var_table) {
        cout << "getting variable: " << v.name << " " << v.value << " " << v.var << endl;
        if (v.name == s) {
            return v.value;
        }
    }
    error("get: undefined variable ", s);
}
```

basically, variables are assigned a name, value, and the boolean is there to determine whether it is a constant or a variable. All variables are declared by Symbol_table::declare() and put into the vector var_table. Symbol_table::get_value() is supposed to read the value of the variable with a certain name.

Whenever I use Symbol_table::get_value() I always get the error, it never successfully returns v.value. Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: what kind of error do you get exactly? i.e. what does the error message say? have you tried to actually read it? it should be pretty self-explanatory, e.g. "there is no get_value method declared in your class"

Comment: Please complete the given code so that we can complie it: turn it into a minimal complete example. As it currently stands this won't even compile

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [errata](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/nmm1/C++/errata.html) - which include a correction to exercise 4:

> s/declare_name()/define_name()/

(Bjarne publishes errata for all his books on his website.)

Answer (score 0):

The member function in your class `Symbol_table` is called `double get(string s);`, but you actually defined it as `double Symbol_table::get_value(string s)`

```
double Symbol_table::get(string s) { //instead of get_value(string s)
```